# ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped stopped working after installing updates

Tags: unity

I had installed unity-revamped package thta adds windows dodge behavior to unity launcher, it was working flawlessly all these but yesterday after I installed some common updates it has stopped working. I tried adding the PPA again and ran update and upgrade but it din't work!

Anybody else facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. I checked with the [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/+archive/unity-revamped) page of unity-revamped PPA and found that the latest package is not yet built, it was added jus a few hours back and its awaiting build.

Here are the screenshots

[image: unity-revamped]

[image: unity-revamped]

After the build is complete try updating and upgrading.

Comment: Oh I had no Idea about the package builds, thanks for explaining it to me. I'll wait for the build to get complete and then try upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

[A new unity release was pushed out yesterday through the official update channels](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity) (Unity 5.16.0-0ubuntu1). You are now running stock unity again and will have to wait for the PPA to update accordingly.